# Update the GUI from another thread in C# - change back to the main thread or not?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know that simplest way to update a label from another thread is:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(DoSomething));
    } else 
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

My question is if instead of the `if` that require to update the GUI from another thread is it possible to change back to the main thread and update the GUI from there ?

Comment: Please explain your question a bit better. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: `it possible to change back to the main thread and update the GUI from there` that is exacly what `Invoke`does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the simplest way to do this is

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(DoSomething));
```

if you call it from another thread for sure, ie. if you know, that InvokeRequired will always be true.

Also, you could use a WinForms Timer to poll for changes of, say, a text field. This timer runs in the GUI thread. That is a pretty good solution if you have hundreds of events per second. Or at least "a lot of". This way you don't have too many switches to the GUI thread (which always take considerable amount of time).

Answer (score 0):

Of course its possible ... you can use class called Dispatcher (System.Windows.Threading). The main purpose of this class is to dispatch "requests/calls" on thread ... and for gui thread there is instance of such dispatcher available for all controls. You can find this instance as member of your Window for example ...

The catch is that you using dispatcher alraedy (in code you posted) in some way ... if you call Invoke inside Form this default/gui dispatcher is used. And "IF" is there for reducing count of invocation from gui thread itself.

It works like "am i in ui thread? No? Then give dispatcher request of calling this same method on UI thread! ... Am i in UI Thred? Yes! Ok, i am doing something."

If you are 100% sure that you call this form other than UI thread, you can throw away that IF and just call dispatcher directly.

```
    MyForm.Dispatcher.Invoke( mydelegate, params[] )
```

Or using some lambda instead of delegate or MethodInvoker ...

```
   MyForm.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action)(()=>{ textbox.text = result; }), null);
```

And at all ... you can store (in form.load event for example) reference to UI Dispatcher to use in different class (some working class doing stuff on other )

If you creating some bigger UI stuff, my suggest for better UI and easier handling stuff like this is: ... consider some study of WPF and MVVM pattern and property change notifications.... it will give you very strong tool with "self updated" and very scalable UI and layers between datas, working threads and UI.

Comment: Dispatcher is WPF, not WinForms!

Comment: Yes,WinForms controls have not dispatcher exposed as member.. however, you can still use Dispatcher even in WinForm.

Comment: Its just class for planing "jobs" on thread. Using **Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher()** you can retrieve instance coupled to current thread. Referencing WindowsBase may be needed.